# Beginner in CSS - text layout and formatting

Tags: css

I am writing my first CSS lines. I want to align all rows of the same block together but I am not sure how to do this. This is what I am trying to do:

[image]

Using regular HTML I would have created a table with as many rows as days and 2 columns. However since CSS is about separating content from presentation I think this violates the principles of CSS. I am thinking that the needed code will have the form:

```
<div>
<div>days</div><div>hours</div>
</div>
```

but I am not sure how the CSS should look like. I don't even understand the CSS defines exactly where to load the different areas.

Thank you

Comment: That is tabular data, so using a table is perfectly fine.

Comment: So defining a table in the HTML code is how it is usually done even when using CSS?

Comment: You could also consider using an `unordered list - <ul>`.

Comment: Yes. A table is not presentation, it's part of the content.

Comment: @DouglasEdward Yes. While `<table>` is no longer the norm/accepted for whole page layouts, using it for data that is uniquely tabular is still a common practice. You can still (and SHOULD) use CSS define the style parameters for the `<table>` layout.

Comment: To clarify, separating content from presentation doesn't mean that you should stop using all tags except `<div>` and `<span>`. On the contrary, you should use as specific tag as you can to define the semantic meaning of the data, and in this case `<table>` is the most precise semantic meaning for the data you have.

Comment: Ok. I was under the impression that the HTML should be pure data with no formatting, and that the entire formatting had to be done in the CSS. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You are correct, but putting data in a table is not formatting.

Comment: Here is a very small sample with tables: http://jsfiddle.net/u6YGX/. See they are not evil at all :)

Comment: @DevlshOne - An *unordered* list? Do you not think that the days of the week come in a given order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use table for table structured data, so that it can be easily styled using css like the way you wanted.

Also Table will be easier to understand when one looks at the source!

*What if the developer later wants to have a striped row or a hover over effect on a row or a column? so use table and leave all the styling part to be dealt in CSS.*

here is a typical html and CSS for your need, view it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7V48/)

HTML

```
<table id="schedule">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>monday</td>
            <td>8am to 6pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>tuesday</td>
            <td>8am to 6pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>wednesday</td>
            <td>8am to 6pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>thursday</td>
            <td>8am to 6pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>friday</td>
            <td>8am to 6pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>saturday</td>
            <td>8am to 6pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sunday</td>
            <td>closed</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#schedule td:first-of-type
{
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 10px;

}

#schedule td:last-of-type
{
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have created a fiddle that should solve your problem.

Here is the [link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daltonpereira/M28eB/)

Below is the HTML and CSS Code

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">

    <div class="push-left">Monday</div>
    <div class="push-right">8am to 6pm</div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="push-left">Tuesday</div>
    <div class="push-right">8am to 6pm</div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="push-left">Wednesday</div>
    <div class="push-right">8am to 6pm</div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="push-left">Thursday</div>
    <div class="push-right">8am to 6pm</div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer{

    width:170px; //width of the container

}

.push-left{
    float:left; //pushes the element to the left
}

.push-right{
    float:right; //pushes the element to the right

}

.clearfix{
    clear:both; //clears any applied floats
}
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think its because here it is way better to either use a list or a table. i would say a table would be the right choice because you could minimize the html & css code and this scenario is exactly what tables are for.

Comment: Oh Alright.Well yes tables is a good choice in this case, but i don't think my solution is wrong either and at the end of the day its up to the programmer which method he is comfortable with. Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

Try

dayshours

Then CSS

```
 .holder{
     clear:both;
 }
 .test{
     width:200px;
 }
```

The holder will keep the lines separate
And the test will define 200px or what ever width you want to each field

Either that or use tables